# Как сделать отправку сообщения в ЛС всем пользователям?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Как сделать так, чтобы бот написал каждому пользователю в личные сообщения дискорд (можно с определенной ролью)?

Comment: Покажите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: стоит, наверно, начать с отправки не всем сразу, а хотя бы первым двум-трём миллионам пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def stack(ctx):
    gui = bot.get_guild(id_guild)

    membrs = get(gui.roles, name="NameRole").members

    for i in membrs:
        await i.send(i)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]